# How to grep only the desired position match in a single line, where there is multiple matches, using regex?

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file with hundreds of links of the form:

`https://file1.mp4" target='_blank'>HD-MQ</a> | <a href="https://file1_v2.mkv`

And, sometimes, the end of the line has `mp4` instead of `mkv`, like below:

`https://file1.mp4" target='_blank'>HD-MQ</a> | <a href="https://file1_v2.mp4`

I already tried `'http.+mp4'` pattern to get a single url, or with `mkv` at the end, but it keeps printing that whole line, because '.+' will do just that, return the phrases that start with `http` and ends with `mp4`.

How could specify the regex (using grep) to match only one of the urls, without that html garbage in the middle?

The final result needs to be `https://file1.mp4` or `https://file1_v2.mkv`, with me specifying which one I want.

Comment: Can you please post some sample input ? Seems like HTML. There's some better tools to parse this

Comment: You’re looking for -o

Comment: `grep -o 'http[^[:space]]*\.mp4' file`

Comment: @GillesQuenot, the inputs are several lines with this exact model, except changes in the "filex" names:
`<td><div align="center">500</div></td><td><div align="center"><a href="https://file1.mp4" target='_blank'>HD-MQ</a> | <a href="https://file1_v2.mp4" target='_blank'>HD</a></div>`

Comment: @nadavvadan the output posted in the question is exactly what I get running grep with -o, the contents, before in the form posted in the comment above, are converted to the mentioned in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the recommendation  you posted gives the following output:
`grep: Unmatched [ or [^`

Comment: Yeah, there is a `:` missing, `grep -o 'http[^[:space:]]*\.mp4' file`

Answer (score 1):

You could exclude the double quote in your pattern:

```
grep -o 'https:\/\/[^"]*\.mp4' file
grep -o 'https:\/\/[^"]*\.mkv' file
```

or both types

```
grep -E -o 'https:\/\/[^"]*\.(mp4|mkv)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-o` or `--only-matching` option in your grep to show only the matching regex.

Then your regex could be like:

```
grep -o 'https:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*'
```

This is not the best regex pattern if you have different text that was shown.